# How to install new listing language definitions?

Tags: listings, miktex, texlive, windows, linux

I Would like to extend the list of supported languages for *lstlisting* environment from *listings* package. I have a definition - for example [pddl language](https://gist.github.com/morxa/9162dfc62261294621fd) defined in *.sty file.

How to add this language definition to my tex installation? I would like to know the procedure both for Windows (MikTex) and linux (TexLive)

On Windows, I was already partially succesful. I enabled the new language by adding the *.sty file to C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings folder. However, it worked only after running the MikTex update.

So what procedure is correct for Windows and what for linux?

EDIT: mimimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}   
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
(:durative-action load-truck
    :parameters (?obj - obj ?truck - truck ?location - location)
    :duration (= ?duration 2)
    :condition (and
        (over all (at ?truck ?location))
        (at start (at ?obj ?location))
    }
    :effect(and
        (at start (not (at ?obj ?location)))
        (at end (in ?obj ?truck))
    )
)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Target (add [language=pddl]):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}   
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=pddl]
(:durative-action load-truck
    :parameters (?obj - obj ?truck - truck ?location - location)
    :duration (= ?duration 2)
    :condition (and
        (over all (at ?truck ?location))
        (at start (at ?obj ?location))
    }
    :effect(and
        (at start (not (at ?obj ?location)))
        (at end (in ?obj ?truck))
    )
)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This leads to `Couldn't load requested language` error without language installation.

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: The recommended procedure is to gather your custom language definitions into a file called `lstlang0.sty` and place that file in your personal (or local) texmf tree; the `listings` package should then automatically pick them up.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the manual of the `listings` package, p. 43:

> Where should I put my language definition?
>
> If you need the language for one particular document,
>   put it into the preamble of that document.
>   Otherwise create the local file `lstlang0.sty` or add the
>   definition to that file, but use `\lst@definelanguage` instead of
>   `\lstdefinelanguage`.

I would rephrase the last sentence as follows:

“Otherwise, add the definition to the local file `lstlang0.sty`
(creating it if necessary),
but use `\lst@definelanguage` instead of `\lstdefinelanguage`.”

And where should “local files” like `lstlang0.sty` be stored (and created if necessary)?  There are two possibilities: the personal texmf tree and the local (machine-wide) texmf tree.

- Use the **local** (machine-wide) texmf tree if you have enough
  administrative priviledges and you want to make a file available
  to all users of your computer.  To learn where the root of the
  local texmf tree is located on your machine, type

  ```
  kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
  ```

  at a terminal (emulator) prompt.
- Use your **personal** texmf tree if you are not allowed to modify
  the local tree on your computer, or if you don’t want to share the
  file in question with other users; indeed, each user’s personal
  texmf tree is located somewhere inside that user’s home directory.
  To learn what the path to the root of your personal texmf tree
  is on your machine, type

  ```
  kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
  ```

  at a terminal (emulator) prompt.

Whatever tree you decide to use, if we denote its root by `MYTEXMF`, the `lstlang0.sty` file should be placed under `MYTEXMF/tex/latex/`, either directly inside that directory or inside a sub-(sub-…-sub-)directory thereof.  It might be necessary to create the relevant directories (*i.e.*, `tex` and/or `tex/latex`).

For example, let’s say you decide to use your personal texmf tree.  On my system,

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

returns

```
/Users/gustavo/Library/texmf
```

(where `/Users/gustavo` is my home directory): this means that I should create a file having the following full pathname

```
/Users/gustavo/Library/texmf/tex/latex/lstlang0.sty
```

(creating also intermediate directories as necessary) and store my personal language definitions in this file.