# wlanguage code source and color in a report with listing

Tags: color, listings, tcolorbox, report

how to put wlanguage code source  in a report

i use this code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
% Pour la gestion du français et des accents %
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
 
\definecolor{darkWhite}{rgb}{0.94,0.94,0.94}
 
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{darkWhite},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    deletekeywords={...},
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    extendedchars=true,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    language=wlangage,
    morekeywords={*,...},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    stringstyle=\color{gray},
    tabsize=4,
    title=\lstname,
}
 
\lstdefinestyle{frameStyle}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=20pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}
}
 
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}
 
\newtcblisting{customFrame}{
    arc=0mm,
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=3mm,
    right=0mm,
    width=\textwidth,
    listing only,
    listing options={style=frameStyle},
    breakable
}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{customFrame}
HExécuteRequête(REQ_CategorieAnneeDist)
HSupprimeTout(CategorieRevue)
POUR TOUT REQ_CategorieAnneeDist 
    HRAZ(CategorieRevue)
    CategorieRevue.AnneeCategorie = REQ_CategorieAnneeDist.AnneeCategorie
    CategorieRevue.DesignationCategorie = REQ_CategorieAnneeDist.Categorie
    HAjoute(CategorieRevue)
FIN

\end{customFrame}
 
\end{document}
```

but latex did not understand the language wlanguage andi don't understand how to change color like this :

[image]

how can i do like this ?

Comment: Is this useful? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374237/1952

Comment: the probleme i use overleaf and not logiciel for latex @Ignasi

Comment: You can include language definitions into your preamble, and if you prefer an independent file, put it on your project folder on Overleaf.